# visual studio code intellisense is not working for dojo amd code

Tags: javascript, dojo, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsd

I have an app.js file which has dojo amd pattern code as follows:

```
require(["dojo/dom", ..], function(dom){
  dom.byId('someId').innerHTML = "test";
});
```

And using tsd, I have installed dojo.d.ts

And also created jsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

But the intellisense is not working. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this?

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this as well.  Did you ever find one?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong

Yes. `require(["dojo/dom", ..], function(dom){` the variable `dom` will have an inferred type of `any`.

## Fix

Use `import/require` and compile with `--module amd` : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand. Here is the JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a4ojr6t6/ Can you show me here?

Comment: A clear example would go far in understanding this answer - thanks